Book in which a boy finds a trap door in an old man's garage that leads to a secret land
I'm trying to find a book by the plot: a young boy rescues an old man from a heart attack, makes friends and looks after his dog. There's a trap door in the old man's garage that leads to a secret land where the boy visits and takes the old sick dog to find a time piece to make the dog younger. There's gold and an evil spell cast over this fantasy land. It involves an evil creature and an ousted princess who is mute.
Sounds very random; it's a better book than I make it sound. 

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

A dog but its not a book by Dean Koontz!

This is Fairy Tale by Stephen King. The dog is called Radar.

Charlie Reade, a 17-year-old boy, lives in Sentry's Rest, Illinois, with his widowed father, George. When Charlie was seven years old, his mother was struck and killed by a van; the resulting grief led his father to alcoholism, from which he eventually recovered with the help of a friend and co-worker, though Charlie remains fearful that he will fall off the wagon.
One day in April 2013, Charlie discovers his elderly neighbor, Mr. Howard Bowditch, injured in his yard. Feeling indebted to a higher power for his father's recovery, Charlie agrees to care for Mr. Bowditch's German Shepherd, Radar, while he stays in the hospital. He also looks after Mr. Bowditch himself when he returns home. During that period, Mr. Bowditch shares with Charlie both his .45 caliber handgun and a surprising stash of gold pellets that he uses to pay his hospital bills.
Several months later, Radar's health has significantly declined, and Mr. Bowditch dies of a heart attack. He leaves Charlie a recorded message, revealing that he was actually 120 years old, and that the locked shed in his backyard contains a portal to another world. In this world exists a magical sundial that was the secret to his longevity. He also reveals the world as the source of his gold and urges Charlie to keep it secret to prevent its exploitation. Determined to save Radar's life, Charlie decides to seek out the sundial and revitalize her.

According to the Sparknotes, the princess, Leah, has no mouth, but communicates via a horse named Falada.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tale_(novel) matches
